# How to change language permanently on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-manifest

I created an Android app with Android Studio that can **change language settings** while executing it from the **top menu button**. Everything works, but whenever I close the app or I rotate the screen the language keeps getting reset to the system one. How to make **changes inside the app permanent**? (Note that inside *AndroidManifest.xml* I have the following line `android:configChanges="locale"` and deleting it doesn't solve the issue.)
I'm using the following code inside my *MainActivity.java*:

```
 public void changeLanguage (String toLoad) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(toLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale= locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String languageToLoad;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.english_menu:  
                languageToLoad = "en";             
                changeLanguage(languageToLoad);
                return true;
            case R.id.italian_menu:              
                languageToLoad = "it";
                changeLanguage(languageToLoad);
                return true;
            case R.id.french_menu:              
                languageToLoad = "fr";
                changeLanguage(languageToLoad);
                return true;               
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save user preference to shared preferences .

```
/******* Create SharedPreferences *******/

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();


/**************** Storing data as KEY/VALUE pair *******************/


    editor.putString("lang_code", "en");  // Saving string

    // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
    editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

create application class and oncreate method of this class set your application local

```
public class BaseJuiceApplication extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

        Locale locale = new Locale(pref.getString("lang_code","en"));
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
         Configuration conf = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
        config.locale= locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @USKMobility. I'm new to Mobile Developing... Do you maybe have a link where I can see how to use **SharedPreferences**? I didn't get if I have to copy your code inside my *MainActivity.java* or to create a new file.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html